# flutter desktop with audio player pakage problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-desktop, flutter-design

When i use this package show me this error "Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version". when i remove this package every things return normal  but i need this package for turn on audio in desktop app .please if you have solution tell me or alternative for this package you are used in your desktop app and don't have problem
[this problem when i made run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLJYE.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.nuget.org/downloads

go to nuget, download nuget.exe latest, then add the path  to env of where you downloaded your nuget.exe  then restart android studio that all!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).